# Java дженерики, stream API и вычисление среднего значения в массиве

Tags: java, исключения, generics, java-stream

Хочу написать класс, который вычисляет среднее значение массива чисел произвольного типа. Написал такой код:

```
package generics;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stats<T extends Number> {

    T[] nums;

    Stats(T[] nums) {
        this.nums = nums;
    }

    double average() {
        return Arrays.stream(nums)
                .mapToDouble(d -> d).average();
    }
}
```

Почему здесь возникает ошибка

> Error:(15, 35) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
>       T cannot be converted to double

Как ее исправить?

Comment: Потому что T extends Number может быть и не дабл(Integer например). Используйте конструкцию вида : "mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue())"

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы преобразуете `T` в [double](/questions/tagged/double) и поэтому выходит ошибка.
2. Зачем прибегать к "мазохистким" способом найти среднее значение ведь, есть проверенная поколениями тропинка?

Код:

```
class Stats<T extends Number> {

    private T[] data;

    Stats(T[] data) {
        this.data= data;
    }

    double average() {
        double sum=0;

       for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
            sum +=data[i].doubleValue();

        return sum /data.length;
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
Stats<Integer> s = new Stats<>(new Integer[]{1, 3, 5, 7});
System.out.println(s.average());
```

---

Даже если задача требует использовать Stream API, тогда используйте вариант [aleshka-batman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213382/aleshka-batman). В коде это будет так

```
double average() {
    OptionalDouble average = Stream.of(data).
            mapToDouble(
                    num -> 
                            num.doubleValue()).
            average();
    return average.orElse(-1);
}
```